# How to use Google cloud platform for hosting a dashboard

Tags: php, mysql, google-cloud-platform, webpack-2

I am developing a sales management dashboard(in the form of a website) to track and record sales. I am using JavaScript ES6, webpack, CSS and HTML to construct the website. I want to host the entire website and the database on the Google cloud platform for faster processing and top notch security. I can't seem to find a way to go about the process.

My preferred option would be to use the conventional way i.e MySQL and PHP. Can someone please help me with the entire process from scratch?

Will I have to put my website in htdocs folder too ?

Thanks in advance.